# Android Studio Dolphin Crashing on Startup Mac M1 Monterey

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, apple-m1

After updating Android Studio to Dolphin, it keeps crashing on startup.
Sharing the message that popped up here.

I am using Mac M1 with Ventura

```
Process:               studio [4152]
Path:                  /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Identifier:            com.google.android.studio
Version:               2021.3 (AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-10-12 09:00:55.5856 +0400
OS Version:            macOS 12.6 (21G115)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        8079434B-2621-B57E-F7C2-059F164371A4

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1E04EB95-F32E-48F2-82EB-2A96F522C211

Time Awake Since Boot: 2400 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1763 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        3

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

Comment: Try clearing the .android, .gradle folders from your mac's home directory. These folders are hidden. You can make it visible by pressing command+shift+period.

Comment: @BijoshMohan didn't work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution to it.

open this file /Users/{USER_NAME}/Library/LaunchAgents/jetbrains.vmoptions.plist
and then remove all `launchctl setenv "*_OPTIONS"`.
save and close it.
reboot your mac.

Comment: good way, solve the problem